# Using python - pywinauto not able to get control of a tab

Tags: python, automation, tabs, pywinauto

How can I get control of a tab using pywinauto? I can easily see the "Compras/Vendas" using print_control_identifiers(), but when I try to click it I'm receiving the error below

The error:

[image: the error]

The tab I'm trying to select:

[image: the tab I'm trying to select]

Edit:

I learned a few things about TabControl reading the documentation, it works very well in some apps, but not in the one I'm trying to automate. My code now:

[my code working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfPi6.png)

[my code not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oinrD.png)

Comment: Could you share the code snippet you have written for selection?
Also, did you try using Swapy ( it is deprecated but works really well.. Auto-generates small code snippets) or Inspect tool ( Can fetch the automation ID of elements).

Comment: I don't think Swapy works well with some elements like tabs, combobox. I made a few changes in my code and now I'm able to change between tabs but not in the app I'm trying to automate

Comment: First try to switch to UIA backend: `Application(backend="uia")`. It will show different hierarchy, but it may work for TabControl (another one from UIA backend).

Comment: When I print control identifiers using "backend=uia" it shows only panes and buttons. As shown in the edit, I can get the tabs from classname "TPageControl", but not the "TcxPageControl", I dont understand the difference